# Is there a direct meaning of the SO logo?

Tags: discussion, logo

I really like the SO logo. Just a simple stack of lines (main's orange and meta's black) unaligned put on top of a bracket.

I know that it relates to programming but, given the detail, I don't get the direct meaning behind it.

Comment: Also: [How was the iconic Stack Overflow emblem born?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122636/284827) on the main Stack Exchange Meta site.

Comment: Well, it's basically an overflowing stack...

Comment: @Tomerikoo This question was originally self-answered. The answer has been deleted by the OP.

Comment: I always thought it's a pile of books collapsing.

Answer (score -6):

As answered on main Meta Stack Overflow logon consist of icon that shows overflowing stack (of paper) next to site name:

[How was the iconic Stack Overflow emblem born?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122636/how-was-the-iconic-stack-overflow-emblem-born)

Comment: the logo is a stack that overflow.(a common programming issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/214741/8620333)

Comment: Never experienced that before, but okay.